# Python3 Event On Specific Key Down

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, terminal, keyboard

I was wondering if there was a way to detect when a key is pressed in python 3 like below:

```
if keypressed('a'):
    print('you pressed a')
```

(Example for simplicity's sake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module can give you more than you want.
Here are some several methods to detect keypress:

**Method #1:**
It will constantly detect your keypress. As you press `a` it will print. Press Ctrl+C to break out of the loop

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        print("You pressed 'a'")
```

**Method #2:**
It will wait for you to press `a` and blocks the whole code until you press `a`. It will detect once only.

```
import keyboard
keyboard.wait('a')
print("You pressed 'a'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the [pynput library](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) can help you. An example from the project documentation:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = mouse.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `keyboard` module with `pip3 install keyboard` and simply write

```py
if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
   print('you pressed a')
```

Comment: how do i import the module?

Comment: @AlexHawking `import keyboard` or `from keyboard import is_pressed` if you only need the `is_pressed` function

Comment: @AlexHawking could you tell me what type of errors?